# How to prevent Android web browser virtual keyboard from giving text recommendations on top of textbox

Tags: javascript, android

How to prevent Android web browser virtual keyboard giving text recommendations to textbox, these appear as white box on top of textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are using cordova:

```
<input type="text" spellcheck="false">
```

or

```
<input autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off/>
```

For native android:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>
```